# the first row is zero in column calculation

Tags: php

I have a sketch of calculation like this

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+ 
    Name          IN              OUT          SALDO
+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+ 
   Cash 8%        $50              -            $50
   Cash 4%        $20              -            $70
   Cash 12%       $70              -            $140
   Claimed         -              $60           $80
   Claimed         -              $20           $60
+------------------------------------------+-------------+ 
               TOTAL SALDO                      $60
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

The table above is what I am expecting to have. However this is the result what I got for now:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+ 
    Name          IN              OUT          SALDO
+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+ 
   Cash 8%        $50              -            0
   Cash 4%        $20              -            $50
   Cash 12%       $70              -            $70
   Claimed         -              $60           $140
   Claimed         -              $20           $80
+------------------------------------------+-------------+ 
               TOTAL SALDO                      $60
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

The problem is it give the 0 saldo in the first row even though the calculation is correct.

Here is my full code

```
    if ($saldo->num_rows > 0) {

        while($objek = $saldo->fetch_object()) {
            $i++;
            if ($objek->eight_percent) 
            {
            $sourceCash = $totalTwelve + $totalEight + $totalFour + $totalTwo - $totalClaim - $totalCashout;
            $totalEight = $totalEight + $objek->eight_percent;
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>Cashback 8%</td>
                        <td> - </td>
                        <td>".$sourceCash."</td>
                     </tr>";
            }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why should it be 50 the first time? You're adding up all those variables, and they're all set to 0 at the beginning.

Comment: That's what I am asking to solve. Because this is the only code that I have that is working for now to make the whole calculation. I am just a middle level in php. Probably a newbie. lol Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a variable before you calculate its value.

For example, lets look at these two lines:

```
$sourceCash = $totalTwelve + $totalEight + $totalFour + $totalTwo - $totalClaim - $totalCashout;
$totalEight = $totalEight + $objek->eight_percent;
```

You're using the value of `$totalEight` to calculate `$sourceCash`, *then* you update the value of `$totalEight`.  On the first iteration, the value of all of those columns will be zero, which is why you're displaying zero.

You probably meant to reverse the order of those two lines.

Comment: That's it. I still don't know anymore how to make the whole calculation of this. This is the better code I make so far. Can you revise it, please?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know what reverse meant until I open my dictionary. lol Thank you.